# How to import mp3 music file to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Like the title, I wanna import mp3 music file to Unity. However, when I tried to import it to Unity it shows this error:

**Errors during import of AudioClip Assets/Audio/Raiden Shogun Battle Theme (Phase 2) - Genshin Impact 2.1 OST.mp3:
FSBTool ERROR: The format of the source file is invalid, see output for details.
FSBTool ERROR: Internal error from FMOD sub-system.
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImporterEditor:OnDisable ()**

What is the cause of this? And possible solution? Thank you

Comment: First your title is very unspecific. Please Change it to something which shows parts of the error. Your Title sounds like a general Question. Please describe the way you imported the file and maybe how you got it/converted it to mp3. 
Some possible solutions: Try another format (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html) or try a new convert of the file (at best with ffmpeg).

Comment: Abt the title: Thanks for the advice. My previous question got someone edited in this way, so I tried to get similar style. To be honest, I'm not really familiar with this system.

Abt the problem: I got a cool music from Youtube and I use this website (https://ytmp3.cc/en41/) to convert mp4 vid to mp3. Then, when I tried to put it in the audio source, it show that error. I prefer to use mp3 since I read that Unity accepted mp3.

Comment: Your Title is to general. It sounds like you didn't know how to import mp3. But you know how to import it. What you really want to know is something like: "FSBTool Error, Invalid File on mp3 import to Unity" Try to get the Keywords into the title. People will more likely help and the question won't get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. You are actually right about the conversion software. Even though Audacity doesn't regconize this mp3 file, this website (https://online-audio-converter.com/) does. I just put it on, convert it to mp3 again, and it works.

Thank you, and sorry if my writing style is not properly. I'm not from IT related background :(

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to put it in an audio editing software like Audacity and export it, that should reencode it and get rid of the problem.